# Does the iOS tabbar/toolbar support buttons/labels/images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitoolbar

I am looking to have a UITableViewController that has a TableView with 2 sections and a tabbar/toolbar that holds two buttons, 1 share button and the other is a button that pushes a view controller. The table view should be underneath the tabbar/toolbar (or the frame should not go under the toolbar/tabbar). If toolbar/tabbar is not possible having a image/button I was thinking of making a view to have as a subview.

Here is what it should look like:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/oKJXAdV.png]

If anyone has any suggestions or ideas of how to go about this, any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you want a `UIToolbar` not a `UITabBar`.

Secondly the only kind of element `UIToolbar` can hold is `UIBarItem`, specifically you are interested in its concrete subclass `UIBarButtonItem`.

`UIBarButtonItem` can either be a system item or hold a custom `UIView`. Since `UIButton` and `UILabel` are all subclasses of `UIView` you can place them inside a `UIBarButtonItem` and add this item to the toolbar.

Comment: Interesting. Would this be better than having a subview and then adding these buttons to that view? Also, will the toolbar allow me to indent and space out buttons like I have in the image?

Comment: Yes, there are two special system buttons, `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` and `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace` that you can insert for spacing.

Comment: Could you give me an example of which one I would you here and how?

Comment: You want a button on the left (with system style UIBarButtonSystemItemAction), a button on the right with a custom view and a flexible space in between.

Comment: Pertonella: I was asking programmatically but I think I got it.

Comment: Well you can easily do it programmatically. There's plenty of examples you can look at. You instantiate three `UIBarButtonItem`, store them in an array and assign it to the `items` property of `UIToolBar`. The first two buttons are just system buttons so you can use `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:`. For the third, first create a custom `UIButton` then use `initWithCustomView:`

Answer (score -1):

Yes,you drag a tabbar to your viewcontroller, an then drag buttons or other things inside of that tabbar.

Comment: -1 poor explanation. Moreover he needs a toolbar not a tabbar.

Comment: yeah sorry, that was I want to say, not tabbar. Anyway, you already explain what I try to say in a "less poor" way.